# MongoDB mongo shell read file issue

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to read a collection I have created in MongoDB.  What does the correct shell script command for "mongo" look like for wanting to read an already created database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend reading the [pymongo tutorial](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html), it does a great job of walking you through simple operations like this.

A few extracts from the tutorial you might find useful (replace localhost with wherever your mongoDB has been hosted, if not on your local. As well as the database and collection names, of course.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
collection = client['test-database']['test-collection']

# Insert a test record into your collection
id = collection.insert_one({"a": 1}).inserted_id

# Read the recently inserted record from the collection by ID
post = collection.find_one({"_id": id})
```

The tutorial has other useful examples, such as how to perform bulk reads/inserts and other useful tricks

Answer (score 1):

**Use mongo shell to gain access database**

```
mongo -u jdoe -p mysecretPassword --authenticationDatabase admin --host "myReplicaSet/localhost:28017,localhost:28018,localhost:28019"
```

**Mongoshell commands to select database context and select data from collection**

```
use mydatabase
db.mycollection.find()
```